# Why Eigenvalues thinks matrices are non-numerical

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I use Mathematica version 9.0.1.

```
matA = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, 3]];

matB = Normal[SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 200, Band[{1, 2}] -> -100, 
 Band[{2, 1}] -> -100}, {3, 3}]];
```

`{matA, matB}` gives

```
{{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{200, -100, 0}, {-100, 200, -100}, {0, -100, 200}}}
```

`e1 = Eigenvalues[{matB, matA}]` gives an error:

> Eigenvalues::exnum: Eigenvalues has received a matrix with non-numerical or exact elements. >>

`e2 = Eigenvalues[N@{matB, matA}]` gives the answer:

```
{341.421, 200., 58.5786}
```

**Question:** Why would `e1` give an error when both matrices are numerical? I don't understand why `N@{matB, matA}` is needed to get their eigenvalues.

Comment: The phrase is "non-numerical ***or*** _exact_". Since the elements do not have decimal places, _Mathematica_ is loathe to introduce imprecision which is required by the algorithm, hence the message. So, by using `N` you tell it you deliberately add the imprecision, making the decision for it.

Comment: @rcollyer You should probably make that an answer.  It *is* the answer.

Comment: @user11946 Can you please choose a display name? The generic "user11946" is hard to remember ...

Comment: @rcollyer - It is subtle but I can see it now. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Szabolcs - I am still quite new to this forum but will chose a display name when I post the new time.

Comment: @user11946. No one is asking you to display your real name. Just change your username to something memorable.

Answer (score 3):

This is rcollyer's comment posted as an answer because as Szabolcs says, it *is* the answer.

> The phrase is "non-numerical or exact". Since the elements do not have decimal places, *Mathematica* is loathe to introduce imprecision which is required by the algorithm, hence the message. So, by using N you tell it to deliberately add the imprecision, making the decision for it.